# Resolving express res.end() error "Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Response<any, Record<string, any>>'"

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I want to create own logging function by extending express.js res.end() method:

```
export async function inOutLogger(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction): Promise<any> {
  
...
  res.end = (...restArgs) => {
    if (restArgs[0]) {
      chunks.push(Buffer.from(restArgs[0]));
    }

    oldEnd.apply(res, restArgs);
    logFn();
  };
...

export default logger;
```

At this particular end() method I get the following TS error

```
Type '(...restArgs: any[]) => void' is not assignable to type '{ (cb?: () => void): Response<any, Record<string, any>>; (chunk: any, cb?: () => void): Response<any, Record<string, any>>; (chunk: any, encoding: string, cb?: () => void): Response<...>; }'.ts(2322)
Type '(...restArgs: any[]) => void' is not assignable to type '{ (cb?: () => void): Response<any, Record<string, any>>; (chunk: any, cb?: () => void): Response<any, Record<string, any>>; (chunk: any, encoding: string, cb?: () => void): Response<...>; }'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Response<any, Record<string, any>>'.ts(2322)
```

[image: TS Error]

Now I know I need to return something but I just can't seem to figure out the correct type of return.

How do I resolve the error?
Thanks.